# Oracle Database JDBC driver cannot read wallet file from Spark

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, ojdbc

### Objective

I'm trying to write to Oracle's ADWC (basically oracle database) from a Spark application running on Yarn. The only way to connect to this database is by using an *Oracle Wallet* file, which is basically a Java keystore.

### Problem

The problem arises when the JDBC driver tries to read the wallet from HDFS. If I include the `hdfs://` prefix the parser in the JDBC driver throws an error and if I don't then it cannot find the file.

### Previous Attempts

1. including the directory in the connect string (prefixed and non) `jdbc:oracle:thin:@luigi_low?TNS_ADMIN=/user/spark/wallet_LUIGI`
2. including the directory as an `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions` with `-Doracle.net.tns_admin` and `-Doracle.net.wallet_location`

All the code is on GitHub, and specifically, the error messages are here https://github.com/sblack4/kafka-scala-jdbc/blob/master/ERROR.md

I've got a working example of the same connection here https://github.com/sblack4/scala-jdbc-adwc

*help me StackOverflow. you are my only hope*

If you need any more clarification don't hesitate :)

#### update (`SparkFiles` attempt)

the code is on a separate branch of the same repository, https://github.com/sblack4/kafka-scala-jdbc/tree/sparkfiles

This error message mystifies me as it seems my JDBC library has stopped trying to read the wallet files. It may be unrelated to the previous problem

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Invalid connection string format, a valid format is: "host:port:sid"
```

I've deleted the other JDBC libraries from my classpath through Ambari as this error could be related to spark picking up an older version of my JDBC library

Comment: Have you gone through https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-data-warehouse-cloud/user/connect-jdbc-thin-wallet.html#GUID-5ED3C08C-1A84-4E5A-B07A-A5114951AA9E  ?

Comment: In a nutshell: the code inside the JDBC driver has no concept of HDFS, it expects a plain file in a plain local filesystem _(or maybe a `InputStream`?)_ So, why don't you use Spark to download the wallet to a local (temp) file _(or maybe open a stream on HDFS ?)_ and pass that to the driver??

Comment: @thatjeffsmith yeah, the connection works perfectly locally

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I'll try the `InputStream` idea but am not sure how I'd pursue downloading the driver locally. That sounds fairly simple if I can then pass that driver-local path to the JDBC in the connection string

Comment: Do you open JDBC connections in the Spark driver **and** executors (i.e. to read/write Oracle data to/from a DataFrame in parallel) with multiple "independant" sessions, or in just in the driver (w/ custom code to run commands not supported by Spark JDBC interface)? Because you can tell the driver to distribute files to its executors, but then the local path will be different and the JDBC URL would also be different...

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I've copied the files to the local executor and updated the path but it seems that the JDBC library can't read from the filesystem. Is there a way to set the default filesystem to local just for that part of the code?

Comment: I think @SamsonScharfrichter was right. However it is [written](https://docs.oracle.com/bigdata/bda411/BDCUG/ota4h.htm#BIGUG76783) in the documentation that "The paths specified in oracle.net.tns_admin and oracle.net.wallet_location should be accessible from all nodes of the cluster." And this one too: "See also: Managing the Secure External Password Store for Password Credentials section in the Oracle Database Security Guide." I would check this guide, maybe there is a better approach there.

Comment: When everything has failed, try silly things... i.e. distribute the Wallet with `SparkFiles` ; generate a random file name in the Driver, broadcast it; make Driver and Executors create a symbolic link to their local wallet under a global path i.e. `/tmp/[random-name]` ; open JDBC connection using that absolute path that's now available everywhere... and clean-up the link if possible.

Answer (score 4):

Here's some code that will help diagnose what the issues is.
It checks and configures everything required to connect.

- JDBC Driver version
- JCE Installed
- Classpath dependencies

Configures

- tns_admin
- ssl settings
- trust/key stores

This is a slimmed down version of what's in sqldev/sqlcl

```
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;

import oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection;

public class JDBCTest {

  public static void fail(String msg){
    System.err.println(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(20, "*")));
    System.err.println(msg);
    System.err.println(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(20, "*")));
    System.exit(1);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    System.out.println("JDBC Driver Version:" + oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver.getDriverVersion());

    // Check JDBC Driver Version
    if (!oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver.getDriverVersion().startsWith("18.")) {
      fail(" DRIVER TOOO OLD!!!");
    }

    // Check JCE Installed
    int maxKeySize = 0;
    try {
      maxKeySize = Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    }
    if (maxKeySize < 129 ) {
      fail(" JCE Policy not unlimited!!!");      
    }

    // Check Classpath

    String cp = System.getProperty("java.class.path");

    String[] cpFiles = {"ojdbc8.jar","oraclepki.jar","osdt_cert.jar","osdt_core.jar"};

    for (String file:cpFiles){
      if ( cp.indexOf(file) == -1 ){
        fail("CLASSPATH Missing:" + file);

      }
    }
    // Wallet unziped location
    String unzippedWalletLocation = "/Users/klrice/workspace/12.2JDBC/wallet";



    String conString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@sqldev_medium";


    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("oracle.net.wallet_location",unzippedWalletLocation);

    props.setProperty(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, "2000");

    // unzipped includes a tnsnames.ora
    props.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin",unzippedWalletLocation);
    props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","truststore.jks");
    props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","<password>");
    props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","keystore.jks");
    props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","<password>");
    props.setProperty("oracle.net.ssl_server_dn_match","true");    
    props.setProperty("oracle.net.ssl_version","1.2");


    props.setProperty("user", "ADMIN");
    props.setProperty("password", "<password>");

    try { 
      // now Connect 
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(conString,props);
    } catch (Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
      fail(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    System.out.println("SUCCESS!!");


  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [18.3 JDBC drivers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/downloads/jdbc-ucp-183-5013470.html)? Passing TNS_ADMIN as part of the connection URL requires 18.3 JDBC driver. Also, are you attempting to connect within the corporate network. In that case, you will need to pass HTTPS_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY_PORT in the connection URL. Let us know. Happy to help with the problem.